# tkinter bad screen distance "10 0"

Tags: tkinter

**My goal is to `pady` this section marked with a red circle slighty down.**
[image]
**Snippet of my code supposed to `pady` the last label down:**

```
self.likviditetsgL = Label(self.left_child, bg=grey, text='Likviditetsgrad,%', pady=(10,0))
```

which results in: `_tkinter.TclError: bad screen distance "10 0"`

There is definitely more than enough place to expand to, so what could the cause of the error be?

**Stuff I have tried:**

- padding the other way around doesn't change anything `"pady=(0,10)"`.
- I could even pad with 0 and it would still cause the same error `"pady=(0,0)"`.
- I even tried rewriting the tuple to a string and it made no different `pady="10 0"`.

*I can post the source code (around 150 lines) if needed.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `pady` option of a label only accepts a single value (eg: `pady=10`), not a tuple. The "bad screen distance" error refers to the fact that the value must be a "screen distance". Normally that means an integer representing pixels, but it can also be something like "1c" (one centimeter), "1i" (one inch), "1m" (one millimeter), or "1p" (one printers point).

You may be confusing the `pady` option of a `Label` with the `pady` option of the `grid` or `pack` methods. The option for `grid` and `pack` methods accept a tuple, but the option for the label itself only accepts a single number.